# How do I remove the right click popup in a tkintermapview-window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkintermapview

I'm trying to remove the popup with the coordinates that appears when the map is right clicked.

I have tried the `unbind('<Button 3>')` but it did nothing.

[image: This is the menu I would like to remove]

The picture above shows the coordinates that pops up on a right click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.unbind()` on the internal canvas widget:

```py
# assume mapview is the instance of TkinterMapView
mapview.canvas.unbind("<Button-3>")
```

Comment: Solved it. Thanks :-)